# runExample() shows listening to server, but does not open any apps

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to learn Shiny in RStudio. Yesterday, I was going through some tutorials on the Shiny website and I could access all the example applications in the package and run them on RStudio locally. Today, when I go into RStudio and try and run the examples in Shiny, it shows `Listening on http....(ip here)` in the console but nothing opens. I can't find the answer anywhere.

The code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
runExample("01_hello")
```

Comment: Update: I restarted my PC a couple of times, and suddenly when I tried to run the code again, it opened the app. However, it crashed about ten seconds later, and when I try and run it again, it again just shows that it's listening and that R has an active session.

Comment: Also, should the app open directly in my browser, or as a standalone window in R? Because I recall yesterday it opened as a standalone window, and the instance that opened now was in my browser.

Comment: Add your updates to your post by clicking `Edit`, then add the extra information there.